# Value uniquess check across several fields of all records?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm new to MS Access and hopefully my question is simple, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer through googling.

I have a simple database with a table it, and there is a subset of fields that must have unique contents. I understand how to set that up so that a *specific* field across all the records must be unique, but I need *several* fields across all records to have unique contents.

For example only one field, in one record, across fields 4 - 10, in all records, can have the number '1' in it. If '1' is in field 5 of record A, it cannot also be in field 8 of record F.

As an analogy, imagine we are building computers, each with 1 or 2 video cards. In the database some of the fields are storing the serial number of the video card installed in that slot. Obviously, serial numbers are unique, and the same card can't be installed in two slots, whether in the same computer, or in two different computers. I need the database to prevent the user from entering duplicate serial numbers. In the example image there are duplicates of the same serial number in different fields of different records. This should NOT be allowed. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ5jw.png)

Is there a built-in way to implement this sort of user entry check? If not, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 2):

You want a unique composite index. To make this

- Go to design view on the table
- Open the `Indexes` editor window
- Go to a new line, enter the name of your new index, select the `Field Name`
- In Index Properties pane change the `Unique` property to `Yes`
- Go to a new line, do not enter an index name, select another `Field Name`

Done

[image]

Edit:

The real issue is that you need to normalize your data. `Slot #1` and `Slot #2` are not really columns. You need to set up your table like this

[image]

Not that I made all three columns a composite primary key AND I made the `VideoCard` column indexed to not allow duplicates

Then when you go to enter your bad data you get this message
[image]
and it's won't let you commit until you enter good data.

If you need to present your data pivoted like your original example then you can do this in a cross tab query
[image]

which will make results like this

[image]

Comment: Thanks Brad!! I did everything you outlined, but once it's all done, I can still enter the same number in multiple fields/records with no warnings or error messages. Is there one more step missing that I have to do?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following your example. Can you post a more elaborate example of the columns in your table and some records which would be good and some which would be bad?

Comment: @gearhead OK, I read over this again, I suspec your table is not normalized. i.e. you have a column for your "thing" then multiple columns for various attributes. but really you need a column for your thing, a column for your attribute then a volumne for the value of that attribute. Then a regular index should do what you want.

Comment: As an analogy, imagine we are building computers, each with 1 or 2 video cards. In the database some of the fields are storing the serial number of the video card installed in that slot. Obviously, serial numbers are unique, and the same card can't be installed in two slots, whether in the same computer, or in two different computers. I need the database to prevent the user from entering duplicate serial numbers. In the example image there are duplicates of the same serial number in different fields of different records. This should NOT be allowed.

![example](http://i.imgur.com/ajbVZjn.png)

Comment: @gearhead see my edits. I'm also going to edit your question with your analogy because I think it is easier to follow that the first example.